# Javascript - Add Class On Scroll not working Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, onscroll

I'm currently trying to change the color of my header `[id ='site-header']` once the page starts being scrolled down. I'm trying to add a class to the header after the window is scrolled more than 100px. I'm developing the website with Wordpress, and for some reason the code works when I have Wordpress' customizer open, but it won't work otherwise.

**HTML**

```
<body class="home-page bp-nouveau home page-template-default page page-id-5 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support geodir_advance_search geodir-page sd-common sd sd-homepage no-js gd-map-auto">
<div id="ds-container" >
<header id="site-header" class="site-header " role="banner" style="">
<div class="container">
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).scroll(function( $ ){
if(jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
   document.getElementById('#site-header').addClass('active');
} else {
        //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
   document.getElementById('#site-header').removeClass('active');
    }
});
</script>
```

Any idea why this might be happening? 
The link for the website is [this](https://rateamdemo.com/rateam/).

Answer (score 2):

I see at least 3 problems with this code:

1) the ID of the element is `site-header` - not `#site-header`, which is just the CSS selector.

2) You are mixing jQuery with vanilla JS - which isn't wrong in itself, but there is no `addClass` method on the object returned by calls to `getElementById`. You need to either call `classList.add(...)` on this "element" object, or (easier, since you're using jQuery already) just use jQuery: `jQuery('#site-header').addClass('active');` (I suspect this jQuery-or-not confusion is what caused the stray "#" in your vanilla JS code.

3) Best practice is to wrap things like this in a callback function passed to jQuery's `document.ready()` - otherwise the event listener may not even be created. (I would assume the `document` object probably does exist at the point this code is run, so this may not matter, but it's still best practice.)

Answer (score 1):

Below code should be work for you. Replace your current jQuery/javascript code with below one.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        var sTop= jQuery(this).scrollTop();
        if(sTop > 100){
            jQuery('#site-header').addClass('active');
        } else {
            jQuery('#site-header').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
})
```